# C++ How to remove node without memory loss?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I just cant get this single linked list to work without memory loss. I've googled around and as far as I can see I do what most suggest. I have also tried "free(deleteNode)" instead of "delete deleteNode". Anyone think they know the answer?

Thank you in advance.

Im trying to insert and remove using this codesnippet

```
List l{};
l.insert(5);
l.remove(5);
```

I'd wager the error is in my `remove` function:

```
void List::remove(int input){

    if(top -> getValue() == input){
        Node * deleteNode = new Node;
        deleteNode = top;
        top = top -> getNext();
        delete deleteNode;
        amount--;
        return;
    }

    Node * tmpNode;
    tmpNode = new Node(top);

    while(tmpNode -> getValue() != 0){
        if(tmpNode -> getNext() -> getValue() == input){
            Node * deleteNode;
            deleteNode = new Node(tmpNode -> getNext());
            tmpNode -> setNext(deleteNode -> getNext());
            deleteNode -> setNext(nullptr);
            delete deleteNode;
            amount--;
            return;
        }
        tmpNode = tmpNode -> getNext();
    }
}
```

My cc file:

```
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

List::List() : amount(0), top(nullptr) {
}

List::List(Node* input) : List(){
    top = input;
}

List::~List(){//destructor
    while( top != nullptr){
        remove( top -> getValue());
    }
}

List::Node::~Node(){//destructor
    next = nullptr;
    //this =NULL;
}

    List::List(List const& other) : List(){
        *this = other;
    }

    List::List(List && other) : List(){ // move constructor
       Node* tmpNode = other.top;
       other.top = top;
       top = tmpNode;
       int tmpAmount = size();
        setSize(other.size());
        other.setSize(tmpAmount);
    }

    List & List::operator=(List && other){ // move assignment
        Node* tmpNode = other.top;
        other.top = top;
        top = tmpNode;
        int tmpAmount = size();
        other.size();
        setSize(other.size());
        other.setSize(tmpAmount);
        return *this;
    }

    List & List::operator=(List const& other){// copy assignment
        Node * tmpNode; 
        tmpNode = other.top;

        while(tmpNode != nullptr){
            insert(tmpNode -> getValue());
            tmpNode = tmpNode -> getNext();
        }

        return *this;
    }

void List::setSize(int input){
    amount = input;
}

void List::insert(int input){
    Node* newNode;
    newNode = new Node(input);
    if(!top){
        top = newNode;
        amount++;
        return;
    }

    if(input > top -> getValue()){
        newNode -> setNext(top);
        top = newNode;
        amount++;
        return;
    }

    top -> putIterator(newNode);
    amount++;
    return;
}

string List::print(){
    if(top == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    string output = to_string(top -> getValue());
    if(top -> getNext() == nullptr){
        return output;
    }
    return top -> getNext() -> print(output);
}

void List::remove(int input){

    if(top -> getValue() == input){
        Node * deleteNode = new Node;
        deleteNode = top;
        top = top -> getNext();
        delete deleteNode;
        amount--;
        return;
    }

    Node * tmpNode;
    tmpNode = new Node(top);

    while(tmpNode -> getValue() != 0){
        if(tmpNode -> getNext() -> getValue() == input){
            Node * deleteNode;
            deleteNode = new Node(tmpNode -> getNext());
            tmpNode -> setNext(deleteNode -> getNext());
            deleteNode -> setNext(nullptr);
            delete deleteNode;
            amount--;
            return;
        }
        tmpNode = tmpNode -> getNext();
    }
}

List::Node List::find(int input){
    return iterate(input).getNext();
}

List::Node List::iterate(int input){
    return top -> iterate(input);
}

bool List::isEmpty(){
    if(size()==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int List::size(){
    return amount;
}

List::Node::Node(int input, Node &nextInput){
    value = input;
    next = &nextInput;
}

List::Node::Node(int input){
    value = input;
    next = nullptr;
}

List::Node::Node(const Node* input){
    *this = *input;
}

List::Node* List::Node::getNext(){
    return next;
}

void List::Node::setNext(Node* input){
    next = input;
}

int List::Node::getValue(){
    return value;
}

/*
void List::Node::deleteNode(){
    delete *this;
}*/

void List::Node::putIterator(Node* newNode){
    if (next == nullptr){
        next = newNode;
        next -> setNext(nullptr);
        return;
    }

    if(getValue() == newNode -> getValue()){
        newNode -> setNext(getNext());
        setNext(newNode);
        return; 
    }

    if(next -> value < newNode -> value && value > newNode -> value){
        newNode -> setNext(getNext());
        setNext(newNode);
        return;
    }

    next -> putIterator(newNode);
    return;
}

string List::Node::print(string input){
    input = input + ", " + to_string(value);
    if(next == nullptr){
        return input;
    }
    return next -> print(input);
}

List::Node List::Node::iterate(int input){
    if (next -> value==input){
        return *this;
    }
    if (next -> value==0){
        return nullptr;
    }

    return next ->iterate(input);
}

bool List::Node::operator!() const{
    if(value == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My headerfile:

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_
#include <string>

class List
{
  public:
    List();

    ~List(); //destructor
    List(List const &other);
    List(List &&other);                 // move constructor
    List &operator=(List &&other);      // move assignment
    List &operator=(List const &other); // copy assignment

  class Node
    {
      public:
        Node() = default;
        ~Node();
        Node(int input, Node &nextInput);
        Node(int input);
        Node(const Node *input);
        Node *getNext();
        void setNext(Node *input);
        int getValue();
        Node iterate(int input);
        void putIterator(Node *newNode);
        void deleteNode();
        bool operator!() const;
        std::string print(std::string input);

      private:
        int value;
        Node *next;
    };

    List(Node* input);
    void insert(int input);
    void remove(int input);
    Node iterate(int input);
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    Node find(int input);
    std::string print();
    void setSize(int input);

   private:

    Node *top;
    int amount;
};

#endif
```

Comment: `Node * deleteNode = new Node;` creates a new node. But you immediately lose a reference to this node: `deleteNode = top;`. In result the newly created node is in memory forever. Should be just `Node * deleteNode = top`.

Comment: How do you know that you have a memory loss?

Comment: You don't solve things like this by searching on Google.  Linked lists should be drawn on paper first, using boxes and lines showing the steps necessary to remove a node.  Then you take what you drew on paper and write the code following the plan you drew on paper.  If there is a bug, you see where your program goes against your plan and you make corrections.  Randomly trying stuff isn't going to cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the new constructor and then setting the pointer, which is creating the memory loss.

```
Node * deleteNode = new Node;
```

Allocates memory for a new node, which you don't want. This is where your memory leak occurs, since you set the to a new address leaving the old memory leaking.

New's function is to allocate heap memory, so only call it when you are choosing to allocate more memory.

The very simple solution is to not call new when you declare the object. Try something like:

```
void List::remove(int input){

    if(top -> getValue() == input){
        Node * deleteNode;
        deleteNode = top;
        top = top -> getNext();
        delete deleteNode;
        amount--;
        return;
    }

    Node * tmpNode;
    tmpNode = top;

    while(tmpNode -> getValue() != 0){
        if(tmpNode -> getNext() -> getValue() == input){
            Node * deleteNode;
            deleteNode = tmpNode -> getNext());
            tmpNode -> setNext(deleteNode -> getNext());
            deleteNode -> setNext(nullptr); // you could probably delete this line
            delete deleteNode;
            amount--;
            return;
        }
        tmpNode = tmpNode -> getNext();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you create a new node in `remove()` at all?

Next, adding getters, setters, and all the other crap to `Node` (which is an implementation-detail of `List`) just serves to complicate `List`. Remove it all (aside from the ctor, maybe).

Consider using double-indirection or other ways to eliminate special cases and the resulting error-prone duplication:

```
void List::remove(int x) {
    auto p = &top;
    while (*p && p[0]->value != x)
        p = &p[0]->next;
    if (*p)
        delete std::exchange(*p, p[0]->next);
}
```

Alternative:

```
void List::remove(int x) {
    auto curr = top;
    curr = nullptr;
    auto next = top;
    while (next && next->value != x) {
        curr = next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    if (!next)
        return;
    (curr ? curr->next : top) = next->next;
    delete next;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, pointer to pointer is clever, but very messy way to handle special cases. It may be a bit more useful for trees (where you should handle left and right children), but for lists it makes things unreasonably complicated. There are cleaner/simpler ways to get rid of duplication.

Comment: I don't see how your comment is related to mine. Actually, I don't understand what you are talking about:)

Comment: Use `prev` node. Update it along with `p`. In the very end check whether `prev == null` and update `head` or `prev->next`. Of course, it's less concise, but, IMHO, much easier to understand.

Comment: @dyukha Using two pointers didn't end up that much longer... and while I still prefer double-indirection, I added it.